# Azure Deployment Centre Error: No deployment data available

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I had a deployment set up with Azure DevOps. Clicking into the Deployment Centre of the Web App, the screen initially says "Fetching deployment data", then "No deployment data available." Refreshing, disconnecting, syncing, does nothing. The site is still running but I can't deploy new versions or disconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Went into Kudu and clicked "Deployments". Got an error message about there being not enough space on the disk. I deleted the LogFiles folder and was then able to see the deployment data again, disconnect the deployment, and redeploy.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) , then it could help other community members who get the same issues to find the useful info more easily and we could archive this thread, thanks:)